# Why does the signature of groupBy contain only one generic?

Tags: scala

This is the method signature:

```scala
groupBy[K](f: (A) ⇒ K): immutable.Map[K, Repr]
```

Shouldn't the following:

```scala
groupBy[A, K](f: (A) ⇒ K): immutable.Map[K, Repr]
```

be more appropriate since its taking a collection of `A` ?

Comment: Where did you take this signature from? Look at the class/trait where it is defined and you'll see where `A` comes from.

Comment: I took it from `https://www.educba.com/scala-groupby/` , I guess if I go to the official doc `https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html` , if A is declared in the class I don't have to redeclare?

Comment: Yes the `A` is already defined at the class level, no need to redeclare it at each method.

Comment: so does `A` have to be unique across the class, I can't declare another generic and name it `A` ?

Comment: You can, but it will shadow the class one and would just cause confusion and would be basically useless. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am just trying to navigate a legacy codebase that is written in scala

Comment: It would be good to learn at least the syntax of the language then, so you do not feel that lost. - Also, since you will have multiple questions then maybe a chat format like **gitter** or **discord** would be better :)

Comment: Currently learning syntax in the doc, but sometimes its hard to search for the answer in the doc, but yeah I think gitter or discord might be a better starting place due to the type of question a beginner would ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to defined `[A]` type parameter on the methods level, because it's defined on the on class level e.g:

```scala
sealed abstract class List[+A]
```

So when method is declared like this `groupBy[K](f: (A) ⇒ K): immutable.Map[K, Repr]` `A` is already known.